# Get-MgApplication is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet - Power Shell

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

I am trying to run Contoso Monetization Code Sample Web App provided by Microsoft as a starting point for moving from paid add-in to SaaS offering. I am stuck at the very end where I am meant to be updating the Azure Active Directory Applications. I get this error

> Get-MgApplication : The term 'Get-MgApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   + $webApp = Get-MgApplication -top 400|Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq ...+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MgApplication:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Here is the code referencing the 'Get-MgApplication'.

```
      $webApp = Get-MgApplication -top 400|Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $webAppDisplayName}
      $webAppSiteName = $armConfigJson.parameters.webAppSiteName.value
      $redirectUris = "https://$webAppSiteName.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc","https://$webAppSiteName.azurewebsites.net/" 
      Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $webApp.Id -WebRedirectUris $redirectUris
```

I have checked online without any success to find if this module can be imported and loaded. I have also checked using the command get-Module to check if is in the power shell module folder and probable misspelled but it not there as well. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any references to Get-MgApplication you can include in your post? Unless it's a custom command someone wrote, I'm not able to find any references to it

Comment: I have added the code referencing the Get-MgApplication as requested.

Comment: Where did you find Get-MgApplication reference that you are using in the code... which module does that belong to?

Comment: The code I have included in my post is a sample code from Microsoft. The required modules to run it are acquired by way of powerShell installation.

Comment: Then you might need to search and include the path of the module that came with the installation to be able to use Get-MgApplucation

Comment: Sorry @Jawad. The required module is not in the modules folder meaning it was not installed and I cant figure out where to find it and that's why I am still stuck.

Comment: Showing this ... Here is the code referencing the 'Get-MgApplication'. ... does not provide the direct link to the doc where you got this from. Please post the actual link to this code block/reference docs. Doing site-specific and string specific searches on MS resources (MSDN, TechNet, MS Docs), show nothing. So, unless you are saying you got this from MS Professional Services, Microsoft Consulting services or in some class you've taken. This is not part of PowerShell and as noted there is no module in the PowerShellGallery.com that contains it.

Comment: Here is the link to the code from GitHub - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-add-in-saas-monetization-sample/blob/master/Deployment/NewApps.ps1

Comment: Ah!, to use any MS Sample code, your environment must be properly set up first. Meaning install all appropriate SDK's, modules, Tools, Dlls', you have not done, for your use case to work. Thus what kwill is pointing to. Azure requires the Graph API and other Azure modules to work beyond that. You may only need what kwill is pointing to, but be sure to look at all the Azure modules, and Graph API information.  Find-Module -Name '*graph*' | Format-Table -AutoSize. There are asterisks around graph - wildcard search, but the comment section is not showing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Microsoft.Graph.Beta cmdlets - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/tree/master